# How to change fonts in website using inspect element of google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

You see website such as facebook for some unknown reason has different font such as what is being used in the options because when I tried using inspect elements it always has different font because I mean its always bold but in the option and customize font I didn't use any of the font that is seen in the elements. Can someone please explain how to change the fonts?

Answer (score 3):

If you can't see the font, it's because it's declared in a separate CSS file. I'd suggest using a CSS editing extension such as [StyleBot](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha). An extension like this will probably work better than editing the page via Inspect Element because with the extension, the changes will be persistent.